# Flutter bloc with streams

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bloc

I'm trying to use flutter bloc pattern in my application. It uses [quick_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/quick_blue/versions/0.5.0-dev.2) library to scan BLE devices. QuickBlue provides a streams with scan results.
My goal is to start scan with one event(emit new state each time device is found) and stop scan with another event.

Problem: I am confused how to cancel an active scan event. Since *scanResultStream* comes from 3rd party library, I can't control it. So, emit.onEach stays active until another *StartScanEvent* fires (thanks to *restartable()*).

I've looked in flutter bloc with stream [example](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_bloc_with_stream), but there stream is created inside application, so user can full control over it.
I'd appreciate any advice.

Here's my bloc code:

```dart
class BLEBloc extends Bloc<BLEEvent, BLEState> {

final List<BlueScanResult> scanResult = [];
final Stream scanStream = QuickBlue.scanResultStream;

BLEBloc() : super(BLEInitState()) {
  on<StartScanEvent>((event, emit) async {
    QuickBlue.startScan();
    scanResult.clear();

    // want to cancel this 
    await emit.onEach(
      scanStream,
      onData: (data) {
        scanResult.add(data);
        emit(DeviceFoundState(scanResult));
      },
    );

    print("finished"); // finishes only on next StartScanEvent
  }, transformer: restartable());

  on<StopScanEvent>(
    (event, emit) {
      QuickBlue.stopScan();
      emit(ScanFinishedState());
    },
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Does the stream continue emitting new data after calling `QuickBlue.stopScan()` ?

Comment: It doesn't, but the stream is never finished. I'm not sure if it's okay to leave it the way it is.

Comment: Did you found any solution? I ran with a very similar case into the exact same problem ... switching from `stream.foreach` to a `stream.listen` leads to the `emit was called after an event handler completed normally` error ...

Comment: @JimPanse Hi! IIRC I switched to Cubit like Mohamed Alsaid suggested.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think i found a solution by not emitting states in async code but throwing another event and handle it. Seems to work fine. Best

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `Stream.listen` so you're able to cancel your subscription at any point.

```
class BLEBloc extends Bloc<BLEEvent, BLEState> {
  final List<BlueScanResult> scanResult = [];
  final Stream scanStream = QuickBlue.scanResultStream;
  StreamSubscription? _sub;

  BLEBloc() : super(BLEInitState()) {
    on<StartScanEvent>((event, emit) async {
      QuickBlue.startScan();
      scanResult.clear();
      
      _sub = scanStream.listen((data) {
        scanResult.add(data);
        emit(DeviceFoundState(scanResult));
      });

    }, transformer: restartable());

    on<StopScanEvent>(
      (event, emit) {
        _sub?.cancel();
        QuickBlue.stopScan();
        emit(ScanFinishedState());
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this approach. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Here is the error:
```emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
This is usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler.
Please make sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers
and use emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to
ensure the event handler has not completed.```

Comment: Seems to be a `Bloc` limitation, didn't realize that. Same approach works for me with a `Cubit`.