# Cancel an action that subscribed to a stream in BLOC

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, bloc

I have a BLOC with an async function that produces events dependending on a use case event stream

```
on<MyBlocEvent>((event, emit) async {
    stream = useCaseResponse.stream;
    
    await stream.forEach((MyModel event) {
        emit(state(property: event.property ...));
    })
}
```

When the user press "Cancel" in frontend, another event is produced which should cancel allt the stream stuff.

```
on<MyBlocCancelEvent>((event, emit) async {
    //should cancel all the stream stuff etc. 
    //also emit the "init" state so that we can start over again when the user press the button
}
```

How can i achieve this? I see two possibilities:

1. Save the stream as a property to the BLOC instance and get it on the other eventhandler method
2. Save the stream to the state and cancel it with the corresponding event

Both seem to be dirty / bad practise

How can i cancel the foreach by using another event? Or how is this done usually?

Edit: Here is the Stream Part from the bloc

```
Stream<PositionDeterminationDto> stream = response.positionStreamDeterminationStream;

await stream
      .forEach((PositionDeterminationDto positionDeterminationDto) {

    emit(state.copyWith(
      currentGpsLocationModel: CurrentGpsLocationModel.fromPositionDto(
          positionDeterminationDto.positionDto),
      status: DetermineLocationStatus.determineLocationProcessing,
    ));
  }).whenComplete(() {
    emit(state.copyWith(
        status: DetermineLocationStatus.determineLocationFinished,
        progress: 0));
  });
});
```

The thing is, if i change from Stream.foreach to Stream.listen, the whole bloc wont work anymore with the error

> emit was called after an event handler completed normally. This is
> usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler. Please make
> sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers and use
> emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to
> ensure the event handler has not completed.

Comment: Maybe I can help you but the `useCaseResponse.stream` looks unfamiliar. What data type is used for useCaseResponse? Providing all the bloc codes might help

Comment: The usecaseresponse is just a transport container for the use case ... every of my use cases has a XyzRequest for request params and a XyzResponse for responses ... the stream therefore is just a proeperty of this response object

Comment: There are many type of stream like `Stream` itself, `StreamSubscription`, etc. Some streams have a function like cancel to cancel the stream. That is why I need to know what type of stream you use. If you don't want to provide the bloc code. I suggest you save the `useCaseResponse.stream` to a private variable inside that bloc. Then add the cancel bloc event to stop the stream. Then your logic from the code you provide is good. You only need to set the `stream` (on the `stream = useCaseResponse.stream`) as a private variable (set to `_stream`)

Comment: @SeptianDika i updated the post. Its the simple `Stream` which returns in the result of the use case response ... it seems with BLOC, anything async that can be `awaited`seems to work, any other (like stream.listen) will throw an error, at least if you emit states in the async code

Comment: It seems the exactly same problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76437712/flutter-bloc-with-streams?rq=2 ... without any solution :/

Comment: I give you two solutions in the answer section. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the `Stream` using `StreamController`.
You can check the doc here, [StreamController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController-class.html).

Since you are not providing all the code from your bloc class I hope my code example helps you a lot.

```
ExampleBloc extends Bloc<BlocEvent, BlocState>{
  ExampleBloc(): super(BlocStateInitial()){
    on<StartStreamEvent>(_startStream);
    on<CancelStreamEvent>(_cancelStream);
  }
  
  /// The private StreamController
  final StreamController<PositionDeterminationDto> _streamController =
               StreamController<PositionDeterminationDto>();
  
  Future<void> _startStream(event, emit) async {
    /// add the stream into streamController
    _streamController
      .addStream(response.positionStreamDeterminationStream);

    await stream.forEach(
       (PositionDeterminationDto positionDeterminationDto) {
         /// function
       });
  }

  Future<void> _cancelStream(event, emit) async {
    /// Cancel the stream
    await _streamController.close();
  }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested it. I hope it works.

---

### Edit

Another solution you can use `StreamSubscription`. since you trying to use `Stream.listen` then using `StreamSubscription` will be work fine. check the doc here, [StreamSubscription](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html).

The example code:

```
ExampleBloc extends Bloc<BlocEvent, BlocState>{
  ExampleBloc(): super(BlocStateInitial()){
    on<StartStreamEvent>(_startStream);
    on<CancelStreamEvent>(_cancelStream);
  }
  
  /// The private StreamController
  final StreamSubscription<PositionDeterminationDto>? _streamSubscription;
  
  Future<void> _startStream(event, emit) async {
    /// cancel the subscription
    /// alternative you can use add(CancelStreamEvent());
    _streamSubscription?.cancel();
    
    /// set the streamSubscription
    _streamSubscription = response.positionStreamDeterminationStream
      .listen(
         (PositionDeterminationDto positionDeterminationDto) {
         /// function / emit / etc
      });
  }

  void _cancelStream(event, emit) {
    /// Cancel the stream
    _streamSubscription?.cancel();
  }
}
```